# Appending command line arguments to a Bash array

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a Bash script that appends a string to a Bash array, where the string contains the path to a Python script together with the arguments passed into the Bash script, enclosed in double quotes.

If I call the script using `./script.sh -o "a b"`, I would like a CMD_COUNT of 1, but I am getting 2 instead.

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a COMMANDS=()
COMMANDS+=("/path/to/myscript.py \"${@}\"")
CMD_COUNT=${#COMMANDS[*]}
echo $CMD_COUNT
```

How can I ensure that the appended string is `/path/to/myscript.py "-o" "a b"`?

EDIT: The full script is actually like this:

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a COMMANDS=()
COMMANDS+=("/path/to/myscript2.py")
COMMANDS+=("/path/to/myscript.py \"${@}\"")
CMD_COUNT=${#COMMANDS[*]}
echo $CMD_COUNT

for i in ${!COMMANDS[*]}
do
    echo "${0} - command: ${COMMANDS[${i}]}"
    ${COMMANDS[${i}]}
done
```

Comment: Why would you want a _single string_ `/path/to/myscript.py "-o" "a b"`, and not an array with three strings, `/path/to/myscript.py`, `-o`, and `a b`? That array is in exactly the state you need to use it as a command line to invoke your program. The array with only one string... not so much.

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) might be a place to start reading for background on why argument lists should be handled as arrays rather than strings containing literal quotes/whitespace/etc.

Comment: (BTW, all-caps variable names are used for variables that change or reflect behavior of the shell itself and other POSIX-standardized tools, whereas POSIX reserves variables with at least one lower-case character for application use -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a single namespace, so conventions necessarily apply to both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea, but if it's what you *really want*, `printf %q` can be used to generate a string that, when parsed by the shell, will result in a given list of arguments. (The exact escaping might not be identical to what you'd write by hand, but *the effect of evaluating it* -- using `eval` -- will be).

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a COMMANDS=( )

printf -v command '%q ' "/path/to/myscript" "$@"
COMMANDS+=( "$command" )
CMD_COUNT=${#COMMANDS[@]}
echo "$CMD_COUNT"
```

...but, as I said, this is all a bad idea.

- [Best-practice ways to encapsulate code as data in bash involve using functions, or arrays with one element per argument.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
- [`eval` results in code that's prone to security bugs.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: The appended string is `/path/to/myscript.py -o a\ b`, not what I wanted...

Comment: When you evaluate `/path/to/myscript.py -o a\ b` as source code in a shell, it has **exactly** the same behavior as `/path/to/myscript.py -o "a b"`. As in, `myscript.py` can't distinguish between the two uses, because they both create the same `sys.argv` list.

Comment: @mck, ...since you're coming from a Python background: the above is like complaining that `repr("""some string""")` gives you `'some string'` as output instead of spitting out `"""some string"""` with the original triple-quotes. They're written different ways, but they're the _exact same value_.

Comment: Sorry @CharlesDuffy, I understand what you mean. It seems it's the script that I'm having is causing some trouble with backslash escapes. I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: I have edited my question. The script doesn't work in the sense that it now got "a\" as the argument for "-o", rather than "a b". Using `set -x` shows that the script is called as `/path/to/myscript.py -o 'a\' b`

Comment: @mck, yes, that's the bug that [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) tells you about, and it's why I've been telling you the only way to run a command that's been escaped this way is with `eval` (thus it being better _not_ to escape things this way at all, and instead to use a separate array per command, as the FAQ I've been linking to instructs).

Comment: @mck, that is to say: You can't run `for command in "${COMMANDS[@]}"; do $command; done`, but you _can_ run `for command in "${COMMANDS[@]}"; do eval "$command"; done`.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot @CharlesDuffy! It's just some code that someone else gave me to improve upon, so unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to restructure it. All I can do is to fudge it so that it works.

Comment: @mck, ...just `$command` without the `eval` doesn't work with double quotes either; it would run `/path/to/myscript.py -o '"a' 'b"'`, failing to honor double-quotes in the exact same way that the above fails to honor backslashes.